# Can Runed Halo be used against the zombie tokens created by Field of the Dead?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it possible to protect oneselves with [Runed Halo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRuned%20Halo%5d) against [Field of the Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bField%20of%20the%20Dead%5d)'s tokens? If so, what card name has to be named?

Answer (score 13):

No, you cannot do that, sorry.

[Runed Halo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRuned%20Halo%5d) requires you choose a card name. This means your choice is limited to names that exist on actual cards printed for the game.<sup>(1)</sup> You cannot make an arbitrary choice: for example “Lightning Bolt” is a valid choice, but “Arnold Schwarzenegger” is not because no such card exists (alas).

[Field of the Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bField%20of%20the%20Dead%5d) creates Zombie tokens, which are simply called “Zombie”.<sup>(2)</sup> There is [no card by that name](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%21Zombie+-type%3Atoken), so you cannot choose the name “Zombie” for Runed Halo. (Tokens aren't cards, so they don't count towards the pool of card names.)

Choosing the name “Field of the Dead” won't grant you protection from the Zombies it creates. It'll mean you can't be targeted or damaged by Field of the Dead, but it wasn't going to do that anyway.

There *is* a loophole for tokens that share a name with a card. For example, [Goblin Wizardry](https://scryfall.com/card/m21/148/goblin-wizardry) creates tokens that will be named “Goblin Wizard”. There is also a card by that name: [Goblin Wizard](https://scryfall.com/card/me1/97/goblin-wizard). This means it's a name you can choose for Runed Halo, which will then also grant you protection from those tokens because they have that name. You cannot however use this loophole for “Zombie”.

---

Citation 1:

> **[201.3.](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr201/#3)** If an effect instructs a player to choose a card name, the player must choose the name of a card in the Oracle card reference. (See rule [108.1](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr108/#1).) A player may not choose the name of a token unless it’s also the name of a card.

Citation 2:

> **[111.4](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr111/#4)** A spell or ability that creates a token sets both its name and its subtype(s). If the spell or ability doesn’t specify the name of the token, its name is the same as its subtype(s). A “Goblin Scout creature token,” for example, is named “Goblin Scout” and has the creature subtypes Goblin and Scout. [...]

Comment: I've always thought it's very interesting how "name a card" means something different in MTG vs Dominion; in Dominion you can name anything you want and it's allowed. Each have their own rules advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Your Gatherer search doesn't actually turn up the card Goblin Wizard (at least, it just shows me an error page); here it is [on Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/card/me1/97/goblin-wizard). Anyway, while that's an interesting coincidence of naming, I'd think a clearer example is the planeswalker [Ajani, Strength of the Pride](https://scryfall.com/card/m20/2/ajani-strength-of-the-pride) which creates explicitly named [Ajani's Pridemate](https://scryfall.com/card/war/4/ajanis-pridemate) tokens (that are even functionally equivalent to the card!).

Comment: There exist the corner case of the set of uncommons from futuresight that made tokens with card names. Llanowar mentor was the green one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Gatherer periodically breaks - the link works now

Comment: @ArcanistLupus I changed the link. It's not a periodic break. It broke because our autocard lookup is broken. [We've requested an update](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/can-the-autocard-feature-be-improved-again). Specifically, the lookup for Goblin Wizard broke because Goblin Wizardry exists—any card that has a name that's the subset of another card's name breaks in lookup. The workaround is to directly link to the Gatherer page or Scryfall page; I opted to link to the Scryfall page.